# I am not using delete before erase to vector. will the pointer always take up memory?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, new-operator, delete-operator

```
std::vector<State*> states;
states.push_back(new MenuState(window));
states.erase(states.begin());
```

it is my code. I am not using delete before erase to vector. new MenuState(window) is a pointer. And if I am not using delete what happend? Should I use? will the pointer always take up memory? and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You're gonna leak a lot of memory.

Comment: how can I solve? thanks for comment.

Comment: Consider using smart pointers

Answer (score 1):

You can use smart pointers: `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`.

For `std::shared_ptr` you can use `std::make_shared()`:

```
#include <memory> //for std::shared_ptr
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<State>> states;
    states.push_back(std::make_shared<MenuState>(window));
    states.erase(states.begin());
    return 0;
}
```

Or, with `std::unique_ptr`:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<State>> states;
    states.push_back(std::make_unique<MenuState>(window));
    states.erase(states.begin());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. What is the difference between uniqe and shared?

Comment: I must first erase from vector than delete pointer. I had error from library. An internal OpenGL call failed in RenderTarget.cpp(152). Expression: glClearColor(color.r / 255.f, color.g / 255.f, color.b / 255.f, color.a / 255.f) Error description: GL_INVALID_OPERATION The specified operation is not allowed in the current state. An internal OpenGL call failed in RenderTarget.cpp(153). Expression: glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)...... I think unique pointers first delete.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't `delete` the pointers stored in the `vector`, you will leak memory. You will have allocated memory and lost control of it and it will continue to remain allocated until your program ends.

In this simple example, you should go through your `vector` and `delete` each pointer before erasing the `vector`. Even better would be to not use 'naked new' and store `std::unique_ptr`s in the `vector` so that when they are destroyed they will return the allocated memory to the system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for any object you create with `new`, you need to call `delete` on it when you are done using it, or else it will be leaked and continue taking up memory.

```cpp
std::vector<State*> states;
states.push_back(new MenuState(window));
...
delete *states.begin();
states.erase(states.begin());
```

You also run the risk of a leak if `push_back()` fails with an exception thrown, unless you catch the exception:

```cpp
std::vector<State*> states;

State *new_state = new MenuState(window);
try {
    states.push_back(new_state);
}
catch (...) {
    delete new_state;
    throw;
}
```

The best way to avoid both issues is to not use `new`/`delete` on a raw `State*` pointer at all. Use a `std::unique_ptr<State>` smart pointer instead, let it handle the memory management for you, eg:

```cpp
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<State>> states;
states.push_back(std::make_unique<MenuState>(window));
...
states.erase(states.begin());
```

Comment: I am gonna cry. I had this:     An internal OpenGL call failed in RenderTarget.cpp(152).
Expression:
   glClearColor(color.r / 255.f, color.g / 255.f, color.b / 255.f, color.a / 255.f)
Error description:
   GL_INVALID_OPERATION
   The specified operation is not allowed in the current state.

An internal OpenGL call failed in RenderTarget.cpp(153).
Expression:
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
Error description:
   GL_INVALID_OPERATION
   The specified operation is not allowed in the current state.